# http.get to a url that includes a dynamic value

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to do a $http.get request from my controller to the url /users/1 where 1 is a dynamic value decided by input from the user.

1 is currently bound to $scope.userid but

```
$http.get('/users', $scope.userid);
```

sends the request to /users not users/1

Comment: `$http.get('/users/' + $scope.userid, data);` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$http.get('/users/' + $scope.userid).success(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Should work

Comment: Thanks this worked, unfortunately it seems $scope.userid is undefined so I have to figure that out now :p